# Weblogic deploy failing after adding spring ws security

Tags: java, spring, maven, weblogic, spring-ws

When I add this maven dependency to my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm able to test my web service with tomcat 7, but when I try to deploy it in a local weblogic 11, I'm getting the following error:

```
<Jun 4, 2013 4:39:19 PM BRT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1370374697780' for task '0'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CompletionCoordinatorPortTypeImpl" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "myproject.war".
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: [failed to localize] WSP_1018_POLICY_EXCEPTION_WHILE_FINISHING_PARSING_WSDL()
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.finished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:1052)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.finished(DelegatingParserExtension.java:183)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.finished(WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:328)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:242)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.getWSDLPort(EndpointFactory.java:550)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:188)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:496)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:539)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:183)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:139)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:68)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:54)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1981)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1955)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyException: [failed to localize] WSP_1014_POLICY_REFERENCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST(zip:C:/var/wls11/servers/Weblogic/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_myproject_war/7nlyde/war/WEB-INF/lib/wsit-rt-1.1.jar!/WEB-INF/wsdl/wsat.wsdl#Addressing_policy)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicies(BuilderHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicySubjects(BuilderHandler.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.doPopulate(BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.java:67)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.populate(BuilderHandler.java:75)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getNewPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:85)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.finished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:1048)
        ... 54 more
'
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CompletionCoordinatorPortTypeImpl" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "myproject.war".
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: [failed to localize] WSP_1018_POLICY_EXCEPTION_WHILE_FINISHING_PARSING_WSDL()
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.finished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:1052)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.finished(DelegatingParserExtension.java:183)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.finished(WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:328)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:242)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.getWSDLPort(EndpointFactory.java:550)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:188)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:496)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:539)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:183)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:139)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:68)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:54)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1981)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1955)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyException: [failed to localize] WSP_1014_POLICY_REFERENCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST(zip:C:/var/wls11/servers/Weblogic/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_myproject_war/7nlyde/war/WEB-INF/lib/wsit-rt-1.1.jar!/WEB-INF/wsdl/wsat.wsdl#Addressing_policy)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicies(BuilderHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicySubjects(BuilderHandler.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.doPopulate(BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.java:67)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.populate(BuilderHandler.java:75)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getNewPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:85)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.finished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:1048)
        ... 54 more

        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyException: [failed to localize] WSP_1014_POLICY_REFERENCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST(zip:C:/var/wls11/servers/Weblogic/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_myproject_war/7nlyde/war/WEB-INF/lib/wsit-rt-1.1.jar!/WEB-INF/wsdl/wsat.wsdl#Addressing_policy)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicies(BuilderHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicySubjects(BuilderHandler.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.doPopulate(BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.java:67)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.populate(BuilderHandler.java:75)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getNewPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:103)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 4, 2013 4:39:19 PM BRT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 1 task for the application '_app
sdir_myproject_war'.>
<Jun 4, 2013 4:39:19 PM BRT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application '_appsdir_myproject_war'.>
<Jun 4, 2013 4:39:19 PM BRT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004 weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CompletionCoordinatorPortTypeImpl" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "myproject.war".
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: [failed to localize] WSP_1018_POLICY_EXCEPTION_WHILE_FINISHING_PARSING_WSDL()
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.finished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:1052)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.DelegatingParserExtension.finished(DelegatingParserExtension.java:183)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.WSDLParserExtensionFacade.finished(WSDLParserExtensionFacade.java:328)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:242)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.getWSDLPort(EndpointFactory.java:550)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:188)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:496)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:539)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:183)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:139)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:68)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:54)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1981)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1955)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java
:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyException: [failed to localize] WSP_1014_POLICY_REFERENCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST(zip:C:/var/wls11/servers/Weblogic/tmp/
_WL_user/_appsdir_myproject_war/7nlyde/war/WEB-INF/lib/wsit-rt-1.1.jar!/WEB-INF/wsdl/wsat.wsdl#Addressing_policy)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicies(BuilderHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicySubjects(BuilderHandler.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.doPopulate(BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.java:67)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.populate(BuilderHandler.java:75)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getNewPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:85)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyWSDLParserExtension.finished(PolicyWSDLParserExtension.java:1048)
        ... 54 more
:com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyException:[failed to localize] WSP_1014_POLICY_REFERENCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST(zip:C:/var/wls11/servers/Weblogic/tmp/_WL_user/_a
ppsdir_myproject_war/7nlyde/war/WEB-INF/lib/wsit-rt-1.1.jar!/WEB-INF/wsdl/wsat.wsdl#Addressing_policy)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicies(BuilderHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.getPolicySubjects(BuilderHandler.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.doPopulate(BuilderHandlerEndpointScope.java:67)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.BuilderHandler.populate(BuilderHandler.java:75)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.policy.jaxws.PolicyMapBuilder.getNewPolicyMap(PolicyMapBuilder.java:103)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

How can I find what is the conflict and how could I solve it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Try adding the scope tag as discussed here? http://relativelyprime.blogspot.com/2010/05/netbeans-68-weblogic-1033-and-jax-ws.html

Comment: Didn't work, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` when I try to start my application through tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dependency this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.wsit</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsit-rt</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I don't get the error anymore. Since I didn't find any alternative, I'll mark myself as correct.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem as well. I'll just add my symptoms here for the google to find: `javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory not found`